# To send slected values ID from the JSON values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an **JSON** file called `workers`.I am displaying the workers name in an **dropdwown(i,e select component)** like this:

[image]

Now i am choosing some workers from the `workers-list` and i am sending that `choosen workers` and the `work-name`to an api(i,e POST operation).Like this:

[image]

But instead of sending `workers name`,I want send their ID's.As in the **JSON**.The **JSON** looks like this:

[image]

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-6dqhru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `[value]` to the `id` property instead of the `name` property like the below:

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let worker of workers" [value]="worker.id">{{worker.name}}</mat-option>
```

also if you want to mimic the exact JSON like in your example, just change your form control name also to `workers` from `staff`